# What is the difference between the two quantified expressions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

For the two quantified expressions, what is the difference?
(a.1) $(\forall x \in A)(P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x))$
(b.1) $(\forall x \in A, P(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x \in A, Q(x))$
Wouldn't they be logically equivalent, in that since $x$ can only hold a singular state value? The only way I found to disprove the two quantified sentences was by negation:
(a.2) $\neg(\forall x \in A)(P(x) \Rightarrow Q(x)) \equiv (\exists x \in A)(P(x) \wedge \neg Q(x))$
(b.2) $\neg \forall x \in A, P(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x \in A, Q(x)) \equiv (\forall x \in A, P(x)) \wedge (\exists x \in A, \neg Q(x))$
For the two expressions to be logically equivalent the negation of the negation would have to be logically equivalent to the original sentences:
(a.3) $ \neg (\exists x \in A)(P(x) \wedge \neg Q(x)) \equiv (\forall x \in A)(\neg P(x) \vee Q(x)) \equiv \text{(a.1)}$
(b.3) $\neg ((\forall x \in A, P(x)) \wedge (\exists x \in A, \neg Q(x))) \equiv (\exists x \in A, \neg P(x)) \vee (\forall x \in A, Q(x)) \equiv \text{(b.1)}$
The issue here though is that, both the sentences (a.3) and (b.3) have differing truth values, so they must not be logically equivalent.

Is this an adequate explanation or am I missing something?

Comment: The $x$ in each bracket is different. Sometimes it helps to substitute in $A, P, Q$ to see if they are equivalent. Let $A$ be animals, $P$ be "is a cat" and $Q$ be "has a tail". (a.1) states that all animals that are cats have tails. (a.2) states that if all animals are cats, all animals have tails. But do cats have tails? Only if all animals are cats.

Comment: Correct; the two are not equivalent. Consider an interpretation with domain the natural numbers with zero and let P the formula (x=0) and Q the formula (x>0). We have that (b.3) is true while (a.3) is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can reduce (based, on that $x\Rightarrow y$ is shorthand for $\neg x \lor y$) question to distribution $\forall$ with respect to $\lor$ and note, that it is not true
$$\left[(\forall x)( R(x) \lor S(x) )\right] \Rightarrow [(\forall x)R(x) \lor (\forall x)S(x)] \quad (\text{False})$$

consider $R$="number is even" and $S$="number is odd" for numbers from $\mathbb{N}$. So you cannot state  $(a.1) \Rightarrow (b.1)$.

However, there is case when equivalence can be hold: there is when one of from your $P,Q$  not depend on $x$.
$$[(\forall x)( R(x) \lor S )] \Leftrightarrow [(\forall x)R(x) \lor S] $$

Comment: Constructive critique is welcome, especially when answer is correct.